# Why can't I embed iframe with javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a video site so I'm sick of writing the iframe code everytime. So I decided to make variables and paste the link only so it will do itself but it doesn't work. Here are my codes:

```
<script>
  var embedlink = "https://youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ";
  var youtubelink = "https://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ";
  document.getElementById("embed").src = embedlink;
  document.getElementById("open").href = youtubelink;
</script>

<iframe width="100%" height="480" id="embed"></iframe>
<a id="open">open on yt</a>
```

Comment: _... it doesn't work..._ **What exactly** doesn't work?

Comment: the only reason the above code wouldn't work is because the document query for `#embed` happens before it is rendered on the page.

Comment: Wrap the code with `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){...})`